# Why is activeClassName of gatsby's Link component not working for my anchor links?

Tags: hyperlink, gatsby

So I am trying to create a one page site and I only want the navigation links to scroll to anchor links upon click. I am wondering though why the activeClassName does not work when I click those anchor links. What I noticed is that the active link that shows upon clicking the anchor links is the parent link.

I have already tried using partiallyActive={false} to the parent link but still nothing happens.

So this is my code:

```
<li>
  <Link className={headerStyles.navItem} activeClassName={headerStyles.navItemActive} to="/" partiallyActive={false}>
    Home
  </Link>
</li>

<li>
  <Link className={headerStyles.navItem} activeClassName={headerStyles.navItemActive} to="/#portfolio">Portfolio
  </Link>
</li>
```

I expect the "Portfolio" link to be highlighted upon click but the highlight remains on the "Home" link. The url changes too but the activeClassName does not transfer from "Home" to "Portfolio". What could be going on here? Does activeClassName not work for anchor links?

Comment: You shouldn't use the Link component for anchors, use the normal anchor tag.

Comment: I have the same issue, and am not using hash links.

Answer (score 1):

As explained on the [`Link` docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#recommendations-for-programmatic-in-app-navigation), you can't use a hash with Gatsby's `Link`:

> Neither `<Link>` nor `navigate` can be used for in-route navigation with a hash or query parameter. If you need this behavior, you should either use an anchor tag or import the `@reach/router` package —which Gatsby already depends upon— to make use of its `navigate` function...

Also note that if you set `partiallyActive` to true on the "/#portfolio" link, then the "/" link will be highlighted given that "/#portfolio" also matches "/".